# Flip a widget in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, widget, kivy

How do I flip a (custom) kivy Widget from Python code? I've tried setting its height or width to negative value, but it actually rotates widget, *ie* flips both axes. The Rotate instruction obviously does the same. I'm aware there is a `flip_horizontal()` method of the Texture, but I don't have a slightest idea how to actually cause it to affect an existing widget rather than in-memory texture from *eg* Atlas.

If it helps, I use kivy 1.9.2 with Python 3.4.3.

**UPD** I tried Scale() to no effect.

```
event.actor.widget.img.canvas.before.add(PushMatrix())
event.actor.widget.canvas.before.add(Scale(x=2.0,  origin=event.actor.widget.center))
event.actor.widget.img.canvas.after.add(PopMatrix())
event.actor.widget.canvas.ask_update()
```

It doesn't work either with or without PushMatrix/PopMatrix. The widget in question is a simple Widget subclass with stretchable image and a couple callbacks for size and position.

Comment: I'm curious why you need to do this?  Why can't you just rotate by 180 degrees?  What kind of Widget?  Do you need an internal text or image to flip?  You could just re-draw a flipped image for example in its container - probably easier than flipping the Widget.

Comment: Because if I rotate eg letter `d` by 180 degrees I get letter `p`, but if I flip it I get either `b` or `q` depending on flip direction. The widget code is available in gist below. Yes, I can do that, but I was hoping there is a solution that doesn't involve making two copies of every image for what should be a trivial operation. And it will be a whole world of pain if a widget is to be constructed at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to achieve your goal is using a Scatter. Here is a full *working* example

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

import random
from kivy.graphics.transformation import Matrix


class MyBox(BoxLayout):



    def later_(self, dt=None):
        self.t.apply_transform(Matrix().scale(-1, 1.0, 1.0),
                             post_multiply=True,
                             anchor=self.to_local(*self.center))
        Clock.schedule_once(self.later_, 1.0)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):


        Builder.load_string("""\
<MyBox>:
    t: s
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Scatter:
        id: s
        do_scale: 0
        do_rotate: 0
        do_translation: 0,0 
        Label:

            pos: s.pos
            size: s.size
            text: "The text below will keep changing using a delayed function..."

        """
        )
        mybox = MyBox()
        Clock.schedule_once(mybox.later_, 1.0)

        return mybox

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The only correction is that at least in my case (Scatter nested within RelativeLayout) anchor coordinates do not need to be translated to local.

Comment: @Synedraacus - no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

How about a Scale instruction with a negative scaling?

If the widget also needs to take touch events, you'll need to modify its on_touch_down to transform them appropriately.

Comment: For some reason I can't get it to work at all, with negative or positive scaling values. Added the code to the question.

Comment: Post a runnable minimal example.

Comment: Will take me some time, it's a rather big project and 'minimal' will not be that small. I'm on it.

Comment: Here's the code https://gist.github.com/SynedraAcus/c8ddb8fe6b57e3a733b051e028b51b97  
And here's the image https://github.com/SynedraAcus/camp/blob/master/Chassis.png

Comment: I can confirm. The image stops displaying at negative scaling values.